# Generate PDF from a list of Images in S3 in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a use case where there are multiple images on S3 and i need to append them to a PDF and simultaneously upload this PDF to S3.
How can this be achieved through a DRF view ?

Reading images from S3 is easy.
Process of uploading PDF to S3 will make use of FileField in models not sure how though plus generating PDF is the main issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate PDF by using [PDFKit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) which in turn, uses https://wkhtmltopdf.org.

You will have to create an HTML template with placeholders for image URLs that can be replaced programmatically.